# Android: app private folder that is not deleted if the app is uninstalled/downgraded

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-internal-storage

Android apps have a private folder to store files that are accessible only to the app. Other apps cannot edit or delete them.

But I know that that folder is deleted when the app is uninstalled or even when the app is replaced with an older version (and also in other cases related to signatures and so on).

I would like to know if it is possible to have a private app folder that is not deleted in the above mentioned cases, so it stays even after uninstalling/downgrading the app. (To me a private app folder is one that other apps cannot change/remove the files that are in it, i.e. malware apps).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. Android learned lessons from prior mobile operating systems, like Windows Mobile, where uninstalled apps would leave all sorts of crap behind, cluttering up the user's storage until eventually the device would become unusable.

The only scenario that resembles what you are seeking is if you use `getExternalFilesDirs()` to work with removable storage — presumably, if that removable storage is not available at the time your app is uninstalled, its files will remain on that removable storage even after that storage is reconnected to the device.